# My PopUpMenu doesn't do anything

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm working on the [Android Developer Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and when I tried to open a activity it doesn't do anything.

Here is my `Main.java`:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Main extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main); 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Probandooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void showPopup(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();
        }

        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.responder:
                        Intent i = new Intent (Main.this, Responder.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                case R.id.reenviar:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reenviando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
        }

}
```

I already declare it on my manifest, I don't know what is

Comment: Maybe you should include some source code, and your logcat.  My guess is that you didn't define your Activity in your Manifest (common mistake).  You need to include your logcat at a minimum (type: 'adb logcat' from a terminal window)

Comment: If you do **everything** the tutorial tells you to, why won't it work if it worked for everyone else?

Comment: @gangqinlaohu it is very possible to follow a tutorial and still miss something or misunderstand something...it happens

Comment: where do you call `showPopup()`? It looks like it is declared in your xml for the `Button onClick`, is this right? If so, post that part of the xml also

Comment: @codeMagic yeah, I was just saying, if you copy all the code, then make changes in an attempt to figure out what it is doing, the problem should be obvious.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu I understand that but it isn't always so obvious, especially if you are new to development. And we don't know what the OP did or did not change. They may not even realize what they changed